# Killing a child thread running a multiprocessing operation

Tags: python, multithreading, image-processing, multiprocessing

I'm new to the multiprocessing thing. I was designing an app where the user can select a video and the app would do facial recognition on it and show it. I used concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor to multiprocess the frames to improve the total time required. My problem is when  I need to integrate the face recognition multiprocessing part in the app, I would need to run the entire thing on a separate thread to keep it responsive.
Usually when the stand alone multiprocessing part runs, it can be stopped by raising an exception. BUt while running on a separate thread, they have their own stack. I have seen people suggesting using a message to verify if the code should keep running or not. But my caller function is not running on a "while loop" to check that.
All i'm asking is, if there is any way I can raise an exception to stop both threads or any other way to stop running that child thread from the main thread. My code is attached below. The sub() is the caller function and the process() is the function that is used as the multiprocessing target.
Thanks in advance.

```py
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
import time
import pickle
import concurrent.futures
import queue
import file_video_stream


def process(sframe, facesencoded, knownfacenames,process_this_frame):
    
    if sframe is  not None :
        if process_this_frame:
            
            small_frame = cv2.resize(sframe, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
            rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1] 
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)   
            unknown_face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)
            face_names = []
                
            for face_encoding in unknown_face_encodings:
                
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(facesencoded, face_encoding)
                name = "Unknown"
                face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(facesencoded, face_encoding)
                best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
                if matches[best_match_index]:
                    name = knownfacenames[best_match_index]

                face_names.append(name)
                
                for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
                # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
                    top *= 2
                    right *= 2
                    bottom *= 2
                    left *= 2

                    # Draw a box around the face
                    cv2.rectangle(sframe, (left-20, top-20), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), 2)

                    # Draw a label with a name below the face
                    cv2.rectangle(sframe, (left-20, bottom -15), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
                    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
                    cv2.putText(sframe, name, (left -20, bottom + 15), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            show_frame = cv2.resize(sframe, (1080,720))
            return show_frame
        else :
            show_frame = cv2.resize(sframe, (1080,720))
            return show_frame


def sub():
    
    list_original = []
    frame_number = 0
    alt_frame_number = 0
    proc_frame = 0
    q1= queue.Queue()
    with open("known.pickle", 'rb') as ki:
        faces = pickle.load(ki)

    faces_encoded = list(faces.values())
    known_face_names = list(faces.keys())

    fvs = file_video_stream.FileVideoStream('Attendance.mp4')
    fvs.start()
    time.sleep(1.0)
    process_this_frame = True
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        while fvs.more():
        #for _ in range (5):
            frame = fvs.read()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            list_element = executor.submit(process,frame,faces_encoded,known_face_names,process_this_frame)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            
            if list_element is  not None:
                frame_number +=1
                #print (frame_number)                    
                list_original.append(list_element)

            else :
                fvs.stop()
                break
            process_this_frame = not process_this_frame

    print ("Total number of frames read:",frame_number)
    #print ("Total number of frames processed:",alt_frame_number) 

    fvs.stop()    
    for res in list_original:
        q1.put(res.result())
               
    while not q1.empty():
        dump = q1.get()
        cv2.imshow('Video', dump)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub()
```

Comment: You are writing the code for the thread. What is the difficulty with making that code only do work that you want it to do? Forget the fact that threads are involved -- this is just a matter of making code not do work that you don't want it to do. You are writing the code to make the thread do the work. You know what the logic to determine what work should be done look like. What's the challenge? Forget about some special "thread" way to do it and just do it.

Comment: You communicate with the other process via queue.
Check out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html
So, when you want to stop the other process, say, when you get an exception, you send a message (say, "quit") on the queue. The other process needs to listen to queue periodically, and exit upon getting this message.